# Error "Cannot find project info" when building .NET Core project with DLL with same name

Tags: c#, unit-testing, .net-core, mocking, .net-standard

I have a .NET Core test project set up to test a .NET Standard library as such:

`A (.NET Standard) -> B (library under test)(.NET Standard) -> C (.NET Core)`

`D (.NET Standard) -> C`

`D` is a mock library of `A`, and its output assembly name has been changed so it's the same as `A`. My hope is that `B` will get compiled with `A`, but that I can replace `A`'s DLL with `D` such that `B` calls my mock library instead.

I've been able to do this in the past when the test project is a .NET Framework project, but with .NET Core I get this error message:

`error NETSDK1007: Cannot find project info for 'C:\NetSdk1007\A\A.csproj'. This can indicate a missing project reference.`

Is this setup possible with .NET Core?